# Is there an attractor that cannot be established using a Lyapunov function?

Tags: stability-in-odes

I was wondering whether there exists an ODE system that has a global attractor that cannot be established using a Lyapunov function. That is, is it true that the existence of a Lyapunov function is not a necessary condition for global attraction in general? And what is the situation if we replace global with local in the aforementioned sentences?